# Folder Security

Tags: security

Is there any way that creater can create folder or file and he can give access to users but folder should not be accessible to admin/root user.Only authenticated user can access that.

Comment: You don't trust your system administrator? In that case, you'd better move your project to another system.  The root user can always bypass any system permissions. The only way you could "hide" stuff from root would be to keep it encrypted (i.e. _keep_ it encrypted and never decrypt it on that system). Since running on a system with an untrusted root user is equivalent to running on a compromised server, you never know what the root user can see or not see (keylogging of passwords etc.).

Answer (score 1):

**No, it is not possible using Linux File Permissions.**

Admin/root has access to any file and directory on your system. You could use encryption (e.g. a Luks container).

Comment: Well, encryption practically speaking means it _is_ possible, no?

Comment: not sure, will root can access mounted luks ? so that would be a limitation....

Comment: You're right, I clarified what I think OP meant ...

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the root user is supposed to have **full rights to absolutely everything** on the system : if everything goes wrong, root must be reliable.

You can create an administration group which you would assign to your system administrators. You could, then, use the linux permissions to precise the access rights to your folders.